# Asp.net user control item command event not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page which has user control in it.

The page data grid bound columns are populated from user control (user control has a data grid whose items are in the form of item templates).

This user control has a column which contains edit save cancel buttons.

The user control also has other columns which are check boxes,drop down lists inside (item templates).

I am using item command event and when Edit link is clicked it should get current row value of a column called "Description" and for testing purpose I am getting this value into a text box called '**Tdval**'.

The Tdval textbox is empty and  when I check break point it looks like item command event is not all firing( as break point is not hit).

I don't understand why.

The page is not posted back when I click Edit link.

Its just the user control link button. Please help me.

Excuse any mistakes and am new to this. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<tr>
<asp:datagrid  ID="dgDetails" 
               EnableViewState="true"
               runat="server"
               onItemCommand="dgDetails_ItemCommand" 
               allowpaging="false" 
               allowcustompaging="false" 
               autogeneratecolumns="false" 
               allowsorting="true"
               backcolor="white" 
               Width="100%" 
               horizontalalign="center" 
               Font-bold="true"
               Font-Names="Verdana"
               Font-size="7pt"
               BorderColor="Silver"  > 
    <columns>
      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ID" Visible="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            HeaderText="Description"
                            HeaderStyle-Width="320px" >
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server">   
                       <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>
                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateColumn>
       <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                           HeaderText="Pr."
                           HeaderStyle-Width="20px" >
                <ItemTemplate>                      
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPrimary" runat="server" Enableviewstate="true"> 
                   </asp:CheckBox>
                </ItemTemplate> 
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" 
                              CommandName="Edit">Edit
             </asp:LinkButton>
   </columns>

 </asp:datagrid>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="Tdval" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
    </td>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
 Public Sub dgDetails_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles dgDetails.ItemCommand

        Select Case e.CommandName
            Case "Edit"
                Dim intRow As Integer
                intRow = e.Item.ItemIndex
            Dim dgRow As DataGridItem
            dgRow=dgDetails.Items.Item(intRow)
                Dim val As String
                val=Ctype(dgRow.Cells(0).Text, String)  (Description column)
                Tdval.Text=val.Text 
      End Select
     End Sub
```

Comment: Is the user control dynamically added to the .aspx page or is it in the markup?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Karl. It is not a dynamically added control. It is code behind. Whenever the data grid has rows, it is displayed on page.                                                             Dim UsrCntrDetails As Details = TempPage.LoadControl("~/Controls/Details.ascx")  TempPage.Controls.Add(UsrCntrlDetails)
            UsrCntrlDetails.RenderControl(OutPutStream)

Comment: Does your page have any validation on it?

Comment: I don't see any  page validation.

Comment: If you put a break point on the `Page_Load` of the user control, does it hit that break point?

Comment: There is no page_load in user control. Instead there is render. Shall I put break point at render?

Comment: I would recommend implementing the `Page_Load` event in your user control, because that fires before edit command and the edit command fires before `Render`, so you need to get further upstream, not downstream.

Answer (score 0):

I thing u can call bindGrid() method after check page.ispostback on page_load like this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            return;
        }
       BindGrid();
    }
```